# OpenSSL and generating CSRs at client side

Tags: openssl, public-key, private-key, csr

I need a favour from you. My infrastructure is IIS 6.0 and windows server 2003.

I need to investigate the use of OpenSSL and the construction of media that can be sent to end users, allowing them to generate CSRs, as well as produce documentation to support the signing of the CSR.

What I mean is, I need to send a CD to the end user with a script that can generate a CSR and a private key at their machine basing on my companies Publickey CA.

1. client can run an utility sent by me via some cd or DVD (May be an openSSL script) needs to accept some parameters so that end user can supply keyword/password data.
2. The script will generate private key and CSR back to my company via some secure way (may be through email, I know it is not safe but some how they send us back CSR)
3. We receive the CSR and we sign it and return to the client.

So I need to document this, so that the end user can understand what he is doing.

So my question is where can I get the script to send to client so that he can generate his own CSR and PrivateKey.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at openssl's [req](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/req.html) command. Invoke req in a script, and provide an ssl config file to the -config option. req will query the necessary information from the user, and write the request into a file (which you also specify on the command line).

**Edit**: you can download openssl from http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
Do read the req man page.